# Is the UK still part of the ECAA since Brexit?

Tags: regulations, uk, eu

Is the UK still part of the ECAA (European Common Aviation Area) since Brexit?

For instance is it possible for a Spanish Air Operator Certificate (AOC) holder to operate a scheduled commercial flight from the UK to Greece?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not still part of the ECAA. The EU and UK made a new agreement for Brexit, which you can [read here](https://commission.europa.eu/strategy-and-policy/relations-non-eu-countries/relations-united-kingdom/eu-uk-trade-and-cooperation-agreement_en). The part about aviation begins on page 534.

Under article 419, it states:

> 3. The Union shall enjoy the right for its air carriers to make stops in the territory of the United Kingdom to provide scheduled and non-scheduled air transport services between any points situated in the territory of the Union and any points situated in the territory of the United Kingdom (third and fourth freedom traffic rights).

So the specific situation you've asked about is legal, not because the UK is still part of the ECAA, but because the agreement between the EU and UK specifically provides for it.